# AWS Amplify GraphQL Unknown Directive in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I have been experimenting with AWS Amplify to generate a GraphQL API and backend. I can create a working backend using the guided schema creation. I chose the Todo example. I can call it from an app built in Android Studio. Queries and mutations work fine. Whenever I use Android Studio to look at the schema.graphql in amplify/backend/api/project/ (where project is the name of the project) I get errors about trying to redefine Todo and using undeclared directive @model. I am sure I am missing something obvious. So any help would be appreciated.

Android Studio 3.6.3 / Gradle 5.6.4 / Gradle Plugin 3.6.3 / JS Graph QL 2.4.0 / Java Language / Amplify CLI 4.18.1 / npm 6.14.4 / node 12.16.2

Am I just wrong trying to use this graphql plugin in this way?

## To reproduce:

Create a project in Android Studio with an empty activity.
From project root run:

```
amplify init
```

Accept defaults.
Run:

```
amplify add api
```

Choose GraphQL, guided schema and select the Todo example. Otherwise take the defaults.
Run:

```
amplify push
```

graphql.schema in amplify/backend/api/project will contain the todo schema

```
type Todo @model {
...
}
```

Where ... is the default fields.

This produces the error

> tried to use an undeclared directive "model"

And also produces 3 instances of the error

> tried to redefine existing 'Todo' type

I can see that amplify has dropped the same json schema into #current-cloud-backend and the project build directory.

I accepted the default .graphqlconfig.yml file.

## Quick update:

I did find I could eliminate the error by doing the following but seems like an unnecessary hack. Though if that is the correct fair enough.

1. I edited the .yml to exclude the #current-cloud-backend copy of the schema and to exclude the build version of the schema.
2. I manually pasted the directive SDL from the Amplify web page on [directives](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives#model) into a graphql file and included it in the yml.

This removed the error about @model.

I also followed the advice in [this article](https://github.com/cjoudrey/graphql-schema-linter/issues/165) which dealt with the error about @aws_subscribe being undefined.

But I still get multiple re declaration errors in the generated schema.graphql in amplify/backend/api/project

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the exact same problem, despite following the tutorial, and am unsure why it should not work out of the box

Comment: Please add the "Quick update" as an answer and remove it from the question body.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar errors. I used the Blog/Post schema template and customized it. After running amplify push and retyping "@model", the errors went away.